# Database migrations when moving framework

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, encryption, data-migration

At my place of work, the decision was made to try and modernise some of our websites, that had been written in vanilla PHP. Given this, we made a move towards Laravel as after some research it seemed a sensible choice.

Recently I have been looking into data migration as we have an application that serves around 500 clients which needs its data moved; this data was encrypted using a custom-made PHP class to handle encryption and decryption.

Therefore, I have taken the following steps to handle the migration

1. Used the decryption function in the application to decrypt the data
2. Moved this data into a CSV file
3. Updated any columns and removed those no longer in use
4. Imported the CSV file using phpMyAdmin
5. Installed a package in my Laravel application that can translate database data into a database seeder that can be used in Laravel

I now have a seeder named UsersTableSeeder that contains all of the old user data.

In my User model I have defined Accessors and Mutators to deal with encryption and decryption through Laravel’s native encryption and decryption functions.

For example, with first_name I have done the following:

```
/**
 * Encrypt first_name
 *
 * @param [type] $value
 * @return void
 */
public function setFirstNameAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['first_name'] = encrypt(ucfirst($value));
}

/**
 * Decrypt first_name if the field is NOT empty.
 *
 * @param [type] $value
 * @return void
 */
public function getFirstNameAttribute($value)
{
    return empty($value) ? '' : decrypt($value);
}
```

This approach works when writing and retrieving data from within the application.

My `UsersTableSeeder` looks like this:

```
    \DB::table('users')->insert(array (
        0 => 
        array (
            'title' => 'Mr',
            'first_name' => 'first',
            'last_name' => 'last',
            'email' => 'me@gmail.com',
            'mobile_number' => NULL,
            'member_type' => 'Active',
            'contact_by_email' => '0',
            'contact_by_phone' => '0',
            'contact_by_post' => '0',
            'remember_token' => 'pOxr1PgwQo',
            'created_at' => '2018-01-29 00:00:00',
            'updated_at' => '2018-01-29 00:00:00',
        ),
```

Which is created by reverse seeding the database I had imported.

The issue is that `\DB::table('users')->insert()` doesn't go via the `User` model so data is not encrypted when the seed is run.

I could change each statement in the seeder to use `User::create([])` but would it be more feasible to write a console command?

Have any of you guys faced a similar situation?

Are database migrations usually handled solely by the database itself as opposed to pumping data through an application?

The package I'm using for reverse seeding is: https://github.com/orangehill/iseed

Comment: Use `Users` (or the name of your user model) instead of `DB::table('users')`. You may have to tweak the array a bit.